# Why does a hamentash have three sides and filling?

Tags: history, minhag, food, purim

All Hamentashen that I've seen have three sides and all Hamentashen have filling.

Why is that?

Comment: NOT related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14551/759

Comment: Otherwise it wouldn't be a hamentasch. Maybe you mean to ask "why do we eat trilateral filled stuff on _Purim_?"?

Comment: @doubleAA It _is_ related, but 1 is a serious question and 1 is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HamanTashen - 3 cornered cookies](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/hamantashen-3-cornered-cookies)

Comment: This is, as noted, a possible duplicate of [an existing question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5663) that asks why triangular cookies are called hamentaschen. If that's not the intent of this question, then I'm not sure what is (see also my comment above). I'm going to close it until such time as the asker clarifies his intent.

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of the later http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15076