# Where did Hamantashen come from?

Tags: food, purim

When/where did the idea of Hamantashen come from?

I have heard:

- Haman's hat
- Haman's Ears

But neither of those make any sense...

Comment: Near-duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69452

Comment: @msh210notreally _near_ but it looks like an actual duplicate.

Comment: http://seforim.blogspot.co.il/2008/03/origins-of-hamentashen-in-jewish.html

Comment: Another idea -- Haman's dice. This is fascinating: https://web.archive.org/web/20140314133528/http://www.jewishindependent.ca/archives/april11/archives11april08-02.html

Comment: Notwithstanding the popularity of other interpretations, I could swear this^ is the actual significance of hamentaschen. (Well, depending on how long they have been around.) This is Jewish humor exactly! It makes me want to eat more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Secular linguists (I believe this is attributed to William Safire) have suggested the most likely possibility that the original was "mon - tashen", i.e. "poppyseed pockets." (*Mon* being Yiddish for *poppy seeds*.) Then at some point someone had them on Purim and made some stretch from *montashen* to *homontashen*.

Eventually modern Hebrew needed some name for the treat and called them *Haman's ears*.

Comment: I heard about some connection between Purim and (poppy) seeds, so it was not by coincidence that someone had them on Purim.