# Source for Haman's hat

Tags: sources-mekorot, clothing, historical-figures, haman

As a little kid, I was always told that a Hamantasch is representative of Haman's three cornered hat. Is there an actual source that says Haman wore a three cornered hat or is it just Folklore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did Hamantashen come from?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15076/where-did-hamantashen-come-from)

Comment: When I was little I used to think it was Haman's (mous)tache

Answer (score 3):

I was told the following by a Rebbe of mine (My Yiddish is sorely lacking, so can't verify it to be true, but why would he make this up?):

In Europe, they made "hamantaschen" out of poppy, which in Yiddish is Mon.  A pocket in Yiddish is a Tasch.  Mon-Tasch, or plural Mon-taschen, (poppy pockets) were a popular purim snack.  The similarity of Mon to Haman caused people to start calling it that, and afterwards the "explanation" came along.

Comment: The problem I have with this explanation is where does the hat come in? How do you get from poppy pockets to Haman's hat?

Comment: @Bochur613: It sounds like the pastry was known as "montaschen" and enjoyed all year round. At some point, perhaps as a Purim joke, it got the name "hamantashcen". Later on, the original name was forgotten.

Comment: Perhaps it's a corruption of Mohn-Törtchen? (Search for it online. Also see Mohn-Tartelettes)

Comment: @Bochur613 Because pockets aren't 3 cornered, and hats can be.  Folklore often develops this way - when you are trying to fit the explanation to the facts.

Comment: @Ephraim As I said, I do not claim to know the Yiddish enough to comment.

Comment: If you do an image search on "Tasche" you'll see that it means handbag too. Now the exact etymology is unclear, but there may be a connection between "pouch" (related to "pocket") and "tasche" which may be derived from "task" which when completed, the compensation would be paid with a "pouch" of coins. See here: http://www.tasche.biz/Etymologisches-zur-Tasche.html . (Note the reference to the Latin "tacere"=keep quite. Perhaps this is related to סתר- hidden and hence we have אסתר? Or is this Purim torah?) The point is that the pastry is a pocket since it contains a filling.

Comment: @Ephraim That's where I was starting from - a poppy pocket.

Answer (score 0):

A possible connection with Haman's hat is that the [Ibn Ezra Writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3.2?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%95%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%20%D7%A8%D7%96%22%D7%9C%20%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%A2%22%D7%96%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%95) that Haman had affixed his idol to his hat. When people bowed to Haman they also bowed to the idol on the hat.

Eating something with a connection maybe symbolizes destroying the idol on the hat. This is just a theory.