# Hamantaschen on Purim

Tags: sources-mekorot, food, purim

I have seen Hamantaschen discussed by the Bnai Yissoschor (early 1800), Zera Shimshon (mid 1700s). I would like to know the earliest source for eating Hamantaschen on Purim?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35810/source-for-hamans-hat/35811#35811

Comment: Near-duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15076